# Is it fine to use submit and ajax at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am doing CRUD for our website. Our implementation is to use submit but in some cases I need to pass data from JS file to my controller (BTW I am using Codeigniter) so I am now thinking if it is standard to use it at the same time. So far it works for me.

Comment: doubt it will work properly

Comment: so far it worked

Comment: as you've shown zero code, it's likely that I'm talking about something that you are not doing

Comment: In your programming logic, you can decide to submit or AJAX. They do not work at the same time. It is okay to implement both and use on once of them based on the logic.

Comment: can you provide some sample code?

Comment: you can use  submit function or submit handler

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, pass it all through JS and basically do below. Note it's about as pseudo code as possible. You will need to make changes for it to even compile.

```
$("#submit").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(normal_stuff()){
        $(this).sumbit();
    } else {
        fancy_stuff();
    }
});
```

Comment: you have to quote around #submit as `$('#submit')` otherwise it will not work.